# error en la lista

Tags: c++, lista

estoy creando una clase lista y me tira este error. Como es la primera vez que hago clases genéricas y tampoco estoy muy familiarizado en c++ quería saber en que le estoy errando. Muchas Gracias. (en lista.h esta todo bien definido)

```
#include "Lista.h"
#include <ProAuto.h>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
Lista<T>::Lista()
{
lista=NULL;
}
template <typename T>
Lista<T>::~Lista()
{
    //dtor
}
template <typename T>
void Lista<T>::Agregarnodo(const T & a)
{
 nodo * aux = new nodo;
 aux->elemento=a;
 aux->siguiente=Lista;
 Lista=aux;
 }
```

error en aux->siguiente=Lista;
expected primary-expression before ';' token
error en  Lista=aux;
expected unqualified-id before "=" token

Comment: deberias copiar el codigo en vez de subir una foto, asi pueden copiarlo para  hacer pruebas y comentarios. saludos

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, ahí realice el cambio. Saludos

Comment: te recomiendo este enlace quiza te pueda ayudar https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/50557/clases-y-objetos-en-c-practica-1/clases-y-objetos-en-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error en aux->siguiente=Lista

`Lista` es el nombre de la clase, no una instancia de la misma. Posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
template <typename T>
void Lista<T>::Agregarnodo(const T & a)
{
    nodo * aux = new nodo;
    aux->elemento = a;
    aux->siguiente = lista; // 'lista' no 'Lista'.
    lista = aux;            // 'lista' no 'Lista'.
}
```

Comment: Era eso. Gracias por la ayuda!